# little boxes in front of text lines after putting contents of multiline textbox in Word document

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word

I have a user form with multiline textbox. EnterKeyBehavior = True. I run the macro, the form opens, I type a few lines of text, pressing Enter after each line. The value from that textbox is put in a variable which is later put in the word document via Find/replace of placeholder text <>.

The text is put in the document and the first line in the multiline textbox entry looks OK, but every other line starts with a little empty box (some Ascii/unicode character I don't know). See pic. [image]

I've tried to replace that little white box by doing a replace on vbCr, vbLf, vbCrLf, Char(10), Char(11), Char(13), from other posts I've found with those solutions, but none of them work for me.  What's the fix?

This is what I have in the form right now and from where I'm trying to clean up the contents of that textbox before passing on the value to the variable that I then put in the word document.

```
Private Sub cmdCompInfoOK_Click()
    txtCompanyInfo.Text = Replace(txtCompanyInfo.Text, Chr(11), "")
    slkCompanyInfo = frmLtrAddress.txtCompanyInfo
    
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

The multiline field is called txtCompanyInfo.
slkCompanyInfo is the variable where I want to put the value from the textbox, and I'm declaring it as Public in the main module, which calls the userform.

Comment: I would suggest saving a document with the little boxes in a cloud storage location and providing a public view link here.

Comment: @FunThomas, your code is coming up with:   13(<CR>),10(<LF>), a carriage return followed by a line feed.  Why can't I replace them with only a carriage return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code into a regular module, it will create a string with information about all characters in the input string.

```
Function DumpString(s As String, Optional specialCharsOnly As Boolean = False) As String
    ' Write all chars of String as ASCII-Value, concatenated as string
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim x As String
        Dim a As Long, dumpMe As Boolean, c As String
        a = AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
        
        dumpMe = Not specialCharsOnly Or a < 32 Or a > 128
        If a = 13 Then
            c = "<CR>"
        ElseIf a = 10 Then
            c = "<LF>"
        ElseIf a = 9 Then
            c = "<TAB>"
        ElseIf a = 0 Then
            c = "<NUL>"
        Else
            c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
        x = a & "(" & c & ")"
        
        If dumpMe Then
            DumpString = DumpString & IIf(DumpString = "", "", ",") & x
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

In your Event-Routine, put a statement like

```
Debug.Print DumpString(slkCompanyInfo)
```

If your input string is to long, you can set the 2nd parameter to `True`, in that case all regular characters are skipped.